# weird language/ charictors after while booting

Tags: boot, usb

when I try to boot from my USB I get these strange characters instead of the dell logo screen:

```
Raikra 'isks kr kphar ia 'ia*
prass ajy kay pk rasparp
```

It seems to ask to press a key, and when I put it in a translator it cannot translate the characters.

Comment: does your USB have anything on it?

Comment: I think it's just English with some substitutions: *"Remove disks or other media"* and *"press any key to restart"* perhaps?

Comment: my usb doesnt have anything on it besides text document backups, some music, minecraft backups, and some MS .bat files on it